# Model Field uniqueness validation error handling

Tags: django, validation, model, uniqueidentifier

I have a model field that is called ( unique_id ) which generates a random string. it is defined in a model call Posts.

```
unique_id = models.CharField(db_index=True, default=generate_id())
```

generate_id function is

```
import random
a = 'ABCDEFJHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefjhijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_-123456789'       

def generate_id(length=6):
        return ''.join(random.choice(a) for i in range(length))
```

django will raise `IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed` if it was not unique.

what would be the right way to avoid duplicate unique IDS at the database level ?

Comment: Note that you should not be calling the function in the default attribute; just pass the callable itself.

Comment: thank you for the heads up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly as @DanielRoseman said do not call function in [`default`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#default), you can set `default` value to callable which is better, because it will call function each time object is created, but if you call it in field definition it will be called once on intepret time

```
unique_id = models.CharField(db_index=True, default=generate_id)
```

Secondly i would recommend using [`UUIDField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#uuidfield), which is does generation of random string for you.

For solving your problem you have 2 approaches. Generate pretty long `unique_id`, at least 12 chars long, and this will almost garanty that you will not have any collision. Or you can add db check in your `generate_id` function

```
def generate_id(length=6):
    unique_id = ''.join(random.choice(a) for i in range(length))
    while Mymodel.objects.filter(unique_id=unique_id).exists():
        unique_id = ''.join(random.choice(a) for i in range(length))
    return unique_id
```

**Answering comment**
Model in method can be accessed through `self.__class__` like in example below

```
class Post(models.Model):
    def _generate_id(self, length=6):
        unique_id = ''.join(random.choice(a) for i in range(length))
        while self.__class__.objects.filter(unique_id=unique_id).exists():
            unique_id = ''.join(random.choice(a) for i in range(length))
        return unique_id
```

But if it will be method you will not be able to add it to field as default value because there wouldn't be `self` instance. But you can try using `@classmethod` decorator. This is only possible if you defined `_generate_id` before instantiating `Field` object and it will only work with `@classmethods`, because in python classes are tiny namespaces of their own.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    @classmethod
    def _generate_id(cls, length=6):
        unique_id = ''.join(random.choice(a) for i in range(length))
        while cls.objects.filter(unique_id=unique_id).exists():
            unique_id = ''.join(random.choice(a) for i in range(length))
        return unique_id

    unique_id = models.CharField(db_index=True, default=_generate_id, max_length=12)
```

But i myself never tried this in real life.

Comment: thank you for the clarification , is there a way to reference the model (Post) from the model itself ? I am trying to define `Post._generate_id` method so I can use it as default inside the model.

Comment: @static you can't have generate_id inside the class.

Comment: Read updated answer. Normally you shouldn't need to use generate_id like method, but if you still want you second example with `@classmethod` decorator

Comment: Fixed few typos and added more info

Comment: great ! thank you so much for the detailed answer, I learned a lot !

Answer (score 0):

So the problem with your model declaration is you have used `generate_id()` with default, so the output of that call is being used as default.

Try using this

`unique_id = models.CharField(db_index=True, default=generate_id)`

This would call the generate id every time when object is created

Ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#default

Comment: it won't, the logic should be correct for your generate_id function. for above question its just same value is given again and again. like while execution of the python file if generate_id returns 10 then for that specific same process every object saved will have value 10. so, having the callable ensures that the function is called every time when object is created